# JGit: Checkout a remote branch

Tags: git, jgit

I'm using JGit to checkout a remote tracking branch.

```java
Git binrepository = cloneCmd.call()

CheckoutCommand checkoutCmd = binrepository.checkout();
checkoutCmd.setName( "origin/" + branchName);
checkoutCmd.setUpstreamMode(CreateBranchCommand.SetupUpstreamMode.TRACK );
checkoutCmd.setStartPoint( "origin/" + branchName );

Ref ref = checkoutCmd.call();
```

The files are checked out, but the HEAD is not pointing to the branch.
Following is the `git status` output,

```sh
$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

The same operation can be performed in git command line, easily and it works,

```sh
git checkout -t origin/mybranch
```

How to do this JGit?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to use `setCreateBranch` to create a branch:

```
Ref ref = git.checkout().
        setCreateBranch(true).
        setName("branchName").
        setUpstreamMode(CreateBranchCommand.SetupUpstreamMode.TRACK).
        setStartPoint("origin/" + branchName).
        call();
```

Your first command was the equivalent of `git checkout origin/mybranch`.

(Edit: I submitted a patch to JGit to improve the documentation of CheckoutCommand: https://git.eclipse.org/r/8259)

Comment: I tried it. it works. its a simple solution. I need to make a change, commit and push to remote. I'll test that and update the thread.

Comment: Much complete answer than mine. +1

Comment: @AdamSiemion: What do you mean by that? `setStartPoint` should work with a tag name, otherwise it's a bug in JGit (please report it).

Comment: @robinst To make it work with a git tag name, `origin/` has to be removed, otherwise [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FORGE-2033) will happen.

Comment: @AdamSiemion: Yeah, but that's the same as on the command line, tags are not namespaced like branches.

Comment: @robinst on the cmd line `git checkout <branch/tag>` work: `git checkout 2.1.2.Final` or `git checkout master`.

Comment: CreateBranchCommand is giving me an error: `CreateBranchCommand cannot be resolved to a variable`. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: is setCreateBranch always be true ? ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587631/how-to-checkout-a-remote-branch-without-knowing-if-it-exists-locally-in-jgit

Answer (score 5):

For whatever reason, the code that robinst posted did not work for me.  In particular, the local branch that was created did not track the remote branch.  This is what I used that worked for me (using jgit 2.0.0.201206130900-r):

```
git.pull().setCredentialsProvider(user).call();
git.branchCreate().setForce(true).setName(branch).setStartPoint("origin/" + branch).call();
git.checkout().setName(branch).call();
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Other two solutions does not work.

Answer (score 4):

As shown in the code of [`CheckoutCommand`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CheckoutCommand.java#L145-L153), you need to set the boolean `createBranch` to `true` in order to create a local branch.

You can see an example in [`CheckoutCommandTest` - `testCreateBranchOnCheckout()`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CheckoutCommandTest.java#L125-L129)

```
@Test
public void testCreateBranchOnCheckout() throws Exception {
  git.checkout().setCreateBranch(true).setName("test2").call();
  assertNotNull(db.getRef("test2"));
}
```

Comment: Good idea to link to test cases, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

you also can just like this

```
git.checkout().setName(remoteBranch).setForce(true).call();
                logger.info("Checkout to remote branch:" + remoteBranch);
                git.branchCreate() 
                   .setName(branchName)
                   .setUpstreamMode(SetupUpstreamMode.SET_UPSTREAM)
                   .setStartPoint(remoteBranch)
                   .setForce(true)
                   .call(); 
                logger.info("create new locale branch:" + branchName + "set_upstream with:" + remoteBranch);
                git.checkout().setName(branchName).setForce(true).call();
                logger.info("Checkout to locale branch:" + branchName);
```