# How to checkout a remote branch without knowing if it exists locally in JGit?

Tags: java, git, jgit, git-checkout

Using ordinary `git checkout` the command works exactly how I would expect it to. Here are the use cases I am trying to allow for with the same piece of code:

1) `git checkout branchname` where `branchname` does not exist locally but does on remote

2) `git checkout branchname` where `branchname` already exists locally

3) `git checkout commitid`

For context, the repository has previously been cloned as follows:

```
repo = Git.cloneRepository()
    .setCloneSubmodules(true)
    .setURI(repoUrl)
    .setDirectory(createTempDir())
    .setCloneAllBranches(true)
    .call();
```

The standard JGit checkout command does not automatically create branches locally. The following piece of code works for scenarios 2 and 3:

```
repo.checkout()
      .setName(branchOrCommitId)
      .call();
```

With the amendment to create a new branch it only works with scenario 1:

```
repo.checkout()
      .setCreateBranch(true)
      .setName(branchOrCommitId)
      .call();
```

Is there a neat solution to this issue I can use, considering the standard Git CLI already provides the automatic functionality within the command I am looking for?

Comment: I've the exact same requirement. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want to do is create a branch if and only if a local one is NOT present. Here's what I came up with using streams where `exampleRepo` is the git repo object, checkout command is the `CheckoutCommand`, and `branchName` is the branch name.:

```java
git.setCreateBranch(git.branchList()
        .call()
        .stream()
        .map(Ref::getName)
        .noneMatch(("refs/heads/" + branchName)::equals));
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution to this I have found so far is to check whether the local branch exists and is an ID in order to combine the two approaches mentioned in the question:

```
    boolean createBranch = !ObjectId.isId(branchOrCommitId);
    if (createBranch) {
        Ref ref = repo.getRepository().exactRef("refs/heads/" + branchOrCommitId);
        if (ref != null) {
            createBranch = false;
        }
    }
    repo.checkout()
            .setCreateBranch(createBranch)
            .setName(branchOrCommitId)
            .call();
```

Comment: The CLI `git checkout` command just tries to use the name as a branch name (tries to resolve to a ref it by adding `refs/heads/`), and if that fails, scans all `refs/remotes/` references for all remotes to see if subtracting `refs/remotes/` plus the remote name matches. If the result of the scan is exactly 1 `refs/remotes/` name, it then act like `git checkout -b <name> --track <the-refs-remotes-name-we-just-found>`. Your code above is not quite the same: what happens if there are 0 or 2-or-more matches?